# How to freeze First Column in tabular Report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Table Report with 70 columns. My requirement is to freeze the First Column as I scroll horizontally.

I have tried checking row headers in Tablix properties, but still it's not working. How can I freeze the first Column?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are the steps for Freezing columns/rows in SSRS

Step1. Go to `Groupings` pane at the bottom and select Advanced Mode.

[image]

Step2a. Select the `Static Member` under `Column Groups` and it will highlight the column where it points to. In the properties mark the `FixedData` to `True`

[image]

For future ref:

Step 2b. For freezing rows you would set the `FixedData` property of Static members under `Row Groups`.

Comment: I can get that now but when i scroll it Fixed column is not clear and able to see the columns at the back in transparent

Comment: Change the Background color to white for the columns you frooze.

Comment: Where is the "Groupings pane"? My report has only the following sections: Page Header, Body, Page Footer.

Comment: How can we solve  the ovelapping column contents for a table with multiple expand collapse columns