# Lock columns in SSRS 2008R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to lock my table header and keep it always visible when scrolling vertically, also I would like to lock columns "Tecnico", "Cod.Commessa" and "Descrizione" while scrolling horizontally.

Is it possible in SSRS 2008R2?
SQL Server BI Dev Studio project of my report:
[image: SQL Server BI Dev Studio project of my report]
This is how the report looks like at the moment, with columns and header not locked:
[image: This is how the report looks like at the moment, with columns and header not locked]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to freeze First Column in tabular Report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416826/how-to-freeze-first-column-in-tabular-report)

Comment: Check the above link. All you need to do is goto advanced mode and set the `fixed data = true` for static members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the small triangle in the column next to the column group and select Advanced Mode. Find the tablix member which stands for the target column. Set FixData True in Properties grid.

[image]